# How to connect to a serial port and read stream of data in streamlit application?

Tags: python, pyserial, streamlit

I have an Arduino connected to my computer via USB. My streamlit service must get this data and visualize it. Here is the code that is responsible for connecting to a port and then getting the data.

```
port_name = st.selectbox("Select PORT", [port.device for port in list_ports.comports()])
start_button = st.empty()
dataframe_widget = st.dataframe([])

if start_button.button('Start', key='start'):
    serialPort = serial.Serial(port=port_name, baudrate=115200,
                               bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
    start_button.empty()
    if st.button('Stop', key='stop'):
        serialPort.close()
        pass
    else:
        while 1:
            if serialPort.in_waiting > 0:
                serialString = serialPort.readline()
                new_data = list(map(int, serialString.decode('Ascii').split()))
                dataframe_widget.add_rows(new_data)
```

The problem appears when a user clicks the Stop button. For some reason, the port is not closed and it is impossible to connect to it again without stopping the whole Python process. How can I  connect to the port properly without those problems?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your while loop is never broken..

I would expect something like this:

```
programm_running = True
listening = False

while programm_running:
    if start_button.button('Start', key='start'):
        serialPort = serial.Serial(port=port_name, baudrate=115200,
                bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
        listening = True

    if exit_button.button('Exit', key='exit'):
        programm_running = False
    
    while listening:
        if serialPort.in_waiting > 0:
                serialString = serialPort.readline()
                new_data = list(map(int, serialString.decode('Ascii').split()))
                dataframe_widget.add_rows(new_data)
        if stop_button.button('Stop', key='stop'):
            serialPort.close()
            listening = False
```